# Function which takes pointer to structure and which variable to display(actually something like 'in' operator in python)

Tags: c, function, struct, parameter-passing

Sorry i m not well versed in c

I want to write a function which takes pointer to structure and which member to display as parameters...

**I was aiming for something like 'in' operator of python ... like i ll pass the key and value to be searched on a array of structure and return it accordingly**

Well i tried working over it a bit and this is kind of what i mean...
it works by addressing..is this fine or is it risky since we are directly working with memory and maybe easier way to do this??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Re{
int x,y;
char a;
}Re;


void initRe(Re *r,int a,int b, char x){

r->x = a;
r->y = b;
r->a = x;

}

void showRe(Re *r,int a,int b, char x){

printf("%d %d %c \n",(*r).x,(*r).y,(*r).a);

}


bool compareAforEqualityChar(void *a,void *b){
//printf("%c    %c \n",*(char*)a,*(char*)b);
if(*(char*)a==*(char*)b){return true;}
return false;
}

bool compareAforEqualityInt(void *a,void *b){
//printf("%d    %d \n",*(int*)a,*(int*)b);
if(*(int*)a==*(int*)b){return true;}
return false;
}

int searchAddressed(void * start , int elesize ,void *x , bool compare(void *, void *)){

    char *ptr =(char *)start; //Use char since one byte

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10;i++){    
        if (compare((ptr+i*elesize),x)){  //call compare function
          printf("%d",i); // index where match is found
        }

      }

}

int main(void){
    Re r[10];

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    char a ='A';

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        initRe(&r[i],x,y,a); //Initialise Struct with some values
        x++;
        y++;
        a++;
    }


    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       showRe(&r[i],x,y,a); // Show All values
    }

    int elesize = sizeof(r[0]);

    int z = 'C';
    searchAddressed(&r[0].a,elesize,&z,compareAforEqualityChar);

//searchaddressed(struct member pointer, struct size, pointer of variable to check, pointer function to chechkwith)
   }
```

Comment: Your structure definition is not a valid C structure definition. It is, on the other hand, a valid *C++* structure definition. And if you're programming in C++ you can do it with templates and a pointer to a member.

Comment: It is not possible, nor is it needed. What is wrong with r.x? If you want to access different variables dynamically (also here, I have a hard time believing you need this) then you can read about a hash_map and implement it or use [an existing implementation](http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/khash.h.html).

Comment: Display the member or return the member???

Comment: Oh, your "edited" version is a **totally other question** - why didn't you **delete the original one** and **make a new one**? It is still possible as we all answered (**uselessly**) so long only your original question and - in my humble opinion - **no one will waste his or her time** to try answer your "edited" one (which may be then "edited" again).

Comment: Oh sorry i m pretty much new to this..so couldnt exactly phrase it..and am grateful to everyone who took their time...i ll edit the orginal part...

Answer (score 0):

No, to start with, you cannot assign values to a structure members during definition because, to assign value to a member needs to have an instance (variable) of that type. It cannot be the variables (members) in the structure definition itself.

You have created a variable `Re` of type `structure Re`, now you have to access each individual member of that structure using the member access operator `.` and assign values, if you want.

That said,

- you cannot pass variable *names* and expect to do some operations with it. Choose a different approach for that.
- `int main()` should at least be `int main(void)` for hosted environment, for standard compilence.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! This functionality is not possible using your method.

What might seem to you in `main` as struct member (like `x`), will be treated by the function as just another variable.

Also, the same function cannot return multiple types of data in C.

You might want to take a look into Unions in C. They will better fit in the scenario.

Short intro:
Unions are almost like structures, but in unions, only one member may be active (or have a value assigned) at a time. They be used as an alternative to the `returntype(according to variable)` part.

Also, try reading some basics of C (struct, functions, etc.) on your own. You might answer your questions yourself!

Comment: There might not be a good reason to implement what OP is requesting, but it is most certainly **not** "not possible". One can simply pass an additional variable (`enum` would be most appropriate), indicating which member to print.

Comment: I was aiming for something like 'in' operator of python ... like i ll pass the key and value to be searched on a array of structure and return it accordingly

Comment: @NewToAndroid: That exact functionality (associative arrays) are not inbuilt in C. However, you can use a good implementation of Hash Tables/Maps for the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not easily done in C.  A function must have a specific declared return type; you can't have a function that sometimes returns an int, sometimes a char.

You could potentially use a `union` as the return type.  Or return an untyped pointer to a value (`void *`) and cast it to the appropriate type.  In either case, the code that calls the function would need to be written with some knowledge of the struct members, which I think undercuts any point to doing this in the first place.

As for the function body itself, you'd basically need to use a `case` statement or a cascading series of `if` statements and hardcode each possible option.  Again, its not clear what you're gaining by doing this.

Comment: I was aiming for something like 'in' operator of python ... like i ll pass the key and value to be searched on a array of structure and return it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use enum visualise structure. Now all u have is to do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    x,
    y,
    a
} ReEnum;

typedef struct Re{
    int x;
    int y;
    char a;
} Re;

int func(Re *r, ReEnum en)
{

    switch(en) {
        case x:
            printf("x == %d\n", r->x);
            break;
        case y:
            printf("y == %d\n", r->y);
            break;
        case a:
            printf("c == %c\n", r->a);
            break;
        default:
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
   Re r;

   r.x = 5;
   r.y = 10;
   r.a = 'A';

   func(&r,x);// should return int 5;
   func(&r,y); //should return int 10
   func(&r,a);// should return char 'A'

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regular function use macro

```
    #define func(stru, el) ((stru)->el)
```

or - which gives the same result

```
    #define func(stru, el) ((*stru).el)
```

Comment: Really Thank you very much... this is kind of what i was looking for....